# How to group by common element in array?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find the solution in spark to group data with a common element in an array.

```
 key                            value
[k1,k2]                         v1
[k2]                            v2
[k3,k2]                         v3
[k4]                            v4
```

If any element matches in key, we have to assign same groupid to that.(Groupby common element)

**Result:**

```
key                             value  GroupID
[k1,k2]                           v1    G1
[k2]                              v2    G1
[k3,k2]                           v3    G1 
[k4]                              v4    G2
```

Some suggestions are already given with Spark Graphx, but at this moment learning curve will be more to implement this for a single feature.

Comment: I don't understand how `GroupID` is formed in your above example

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for a solution without using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth  GroupID  just one uniqueid for one group of data. At this moment we planning to use monotonicallyIncreasingId for each group.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski yes, as I explained you we do not have much time to understand and implement graph theory. Trying to achieve same in different way using spark-core and spark-sql

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use a pre-made solution instead of "understanding and implementing graph theory". Graphframes can come to your help: https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html#connected-components

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Include [`graphframes`](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes) (the latest supported Spark version is 2.1, but it should support 2.2 as well, if you use newer you'll have to build your own with 2.3 patch) replacing `XXX` with Spark version and `YYY` with Scala version:

```
spark.jars.packages  graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-sparkXXX-s_YYY
```

Add explode keys:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
   (Seq("k1", "k2"), "v1"), (Seq("k2"), "v2"),
   (Seq("k3", "k2"), "v3"), (Seq("k4"), "v4")
).toDF("key", "value")

val edges = df.select(
  explode($"key") as "src", $"value" as "dst")
```

Convert to `graphframe`:

```scala
import org.graphframes._

val gf = GraphFrame.fromEdges(edges)
```

Set checkpoint directory (if not set):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val path: String = ???
val spark: SparkSession = ???
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(path)
```

Find connected components:

```scala
val components = GraphFrame.fromEdges(edges).connectedComponents.setAlgorithm("graphx").run
```

Join result with input data:

```scala
 val result = components.where($"id".startsWith("v")).toDF("value", "group").join(df, Seq("value"))
```

Check result:

```scala
result.show

// +-----+------------+--------+
// |value|       group|     key|
// +-----+------------+--------+
// |   v3|489626271744|[k3, k2]|
// |   v2|489626271744|    [k2]|
// |   v4|532575944704|    [k4]|
// |   v1|489626271744|[k1, k2]|
// +-----+------------+--------+
```