# group by count with expression

Tags: apache-spark, graph

I have a spark data frame where 2 columns can represent the id: `first_id`, `second_id`.
I want to count rows where the grouping will be :

```
a.first_id = b.first_id OR a.second_id = b.second_id
```

I couldn't find examples of that, and I understand that the problem is that the grouping key is not deterministic (2 unrelated rows might end up in the same group since there is a third row connecting them). my questions are :

1. Mathematically what is the algorithm to solve this? (graph query? something else?)
2. Is there a spark implementation for that?

Comment: [How to group by common element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43915762/8371915) might help you.

Comment: great reference!!! thanks