# Scala Spark- Doing a GroupBy using Array[String] to match records if contained within other record element as a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my Scala program, I am dealing with a problem to combine the result from multiple levels of GroupBy. 
The dataset that I am using is quite big. As a small sample, I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
val df = (Seq(("f1", "l1", "loy1", null, "s1"),
  ("f1", "l1", "loy1", "e1", "s1"),
  ("f2", "l2", "loy2", "e2", "s2"),
  ("f2", "l2", "loy2", "e3", null),
  ("f1", "l1", null , "e1", "s3"),
  ("f1", "l1", null , "e2", "s3"),
  ("f2", "l2", null , null, "s4")
).toDF("F", "L", "Loy", "Email", "State"))


+---+---+----+-----+-----+
|  F|  L| Loy|Email|State|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
| f1| l1|loy1| null|   s1|
| f1| l1|loy1|   e1|   s1|
| f2| l2|loy2|   e2|   s2|
| f2| l2|loy2|   e3| null|
| f1| l1|null|   e1|   s3|
| f1| l1|null|   e2|   s3|
| f2| l2|null| null|   s4|
+---+---+----+-----+-----+
```

For the **first level groupBy** I use the following script, to obtain the result based on the same **(F, L, Loy) columns**:

```
df.groupBy("F", "L", "Loy").agg(collect_set($"Email").alias("Email"), collect_set($"State").alias("State")).show
```

The result is like this:

```
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
|  F|  L| Loy|   Email|State|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
| f1| l1|null|[e1, e2]| [s3]|
| f2| l2|loy2|[e2, e3]| [s2]|
| f1| l1|loy1|    [e1]| [s1]|
| f2| l2|null|      []| [s4]|
+---+---+----+--------+-----+
```

The problem that I am dealing with is that how can I perform the **second level groupBy**, which is based on the condition **(F, L, Email)** and takes as an input **F** and **L** as a String while **Email** column as an Array[String]. This groupBy should return a result as followed:

```
+---+---+------+--------+---------+
|  F|  L|   Loy|   Email|    State|
+---+---+------+--------+---------+
| f1| l1|[loy1]|[e1, e2]| [s3, s1]|
| f2| l2|[loy2]|[e2, e3]|     [s2]|
| f2| l2|  null|      []|     [s4]|
+---+---+------+--------+---------+
```

The main goal is to reduce the number of entries as much as possible by applying groupBy in different levels. I am quite new to Scala and any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by common element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43915762/10465355)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by common element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915762/how-to-group-by-common-element-in-array)

Comment: Looking for some solution other than graphframes.