# How to group by similar element in the lists

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my program I want to perform a **groupBy** operation on the dataframe using the common element in the list. For example the following dataframe:

```
visitorId   |trackingIds     |emailIds
+-----------+----------------+--------
[a158]      |[666b,666b,777c]|[12]
[7g21]      |[c0b5,c0b4]     |[45, 87]
[p9098]     |[666b]          |[90]
[8u7t]      |[c0b5]          |[40]
```

Should be grouped by the column **trackingIds**, which is actually a List[String]

```
visitorId          |trackingIds     |emailIds
+------------------+----------------+------------
[a158, p9098]      |[666b,666b,777c]|[12, 90]
[7g21, 8u7t]       |[c0b5,c0b4]     |[45, 87, 40]
```

I have a solution using a simple function that finds the element in other rows and merges accordingly but looking for a solution that would be cost effective, as the operation is to be performed on a big dataframe with millions of rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group by common element in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915762/how-to-group-by-common-element-in-array)

Comment: Looking for some solution other than graphframes.