# Group by elements in list

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie in PySpark.
I created spark dataframe,and I have a column "Countries" which contains list of countries.
How can i groupBy my dataframe by single countries which exists in Country list

```
+-----------------+
|        countries|
+-----------------+
|  [Россия, Китай]|
| [Великобритания]|
|       [Норвегия]|
|         [Россия]|
|               []|
|            [США]|
|         [Россия]|
|            [США]|
|               []|
|         [Россия]|
|               []|
|               []|
|         [Италия]|
| [Россия, Грузия]|
|            [США]|
|               []|
|               []|
|               []|
|[Великобритания ]|
|       [Беларусь]|
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples) your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look in the official PySpark doc. With the groupBy, which is part of the pyspark.sql module, function u can group your dataframe. [Latest PySpark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy)
If you want to group by multiple cols you can just pass a list with *listname.

```
data_frame_name.groupBy("countries")
```

Comment: I want to groupBy by elements in lists

Comment: Can you be a little bit more detailed? Which list?

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL? Do you want something similar like "group by colname"?
Or can you show me the expected output

Comment: Every row contains column "countries" with the list inside (for example [Russia, China],[],[Italy] and etc.), so i am trying to groupBy by elements which contains  inside the lists (For example I need to group by Russia,China,Italy)

Comment: Expected output :
Россия-5
Китай-1
Великобритания-2
Норвегия-1
США-3
Италия-1
Грузия-1
Беларусь-1

Comment: Maybe you can take a look on this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915762/how-to-group-by-common-element-in-array, otherwise its not done with a single command