# Group by date range overlapping using PySpark

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to perform a kind of grouping with users who have used the same IP in a overlapping range of dates.

This will let me know if two users share the same house because they have the same IP at the same time.

Also, I've been trying to implement it, but I can't find a way to do it with PySpark SQL.
In fact, I think it can't be done with PySpark, and probably requires some other graph-oriented library.

The problem is the following:

```
| ip          | user       | start_date | end_date   |
| ----------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 192.168.1.1 | a          | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 |
| 192.168.1.1 | a          | 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-07 |
| 192.168.1.1 | b          | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-09 |
| 192.168.1.1 | c          | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-11 |
| 192.168.1.2 | d          | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-11 |
| 192.168.1.2 | e          | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-11 |
| 192.168.1.2 | f          | 2022-01-16 | 2022-01-18 |
```

As we can see:

- the users `a`, `b` overlaps in range and same `ip`.
- the users `b`, `c` overlaps in range and same `ip`.
- indirectly the users `a` and `c` are in the same group.
- the users `d`, `e` overlaps in range and same `ip`.
- the user `f` not overlap with respect other user.

Expected output:

```
| ip          | users       | date_ranges
| ----------- | ----------- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 192.168.1.1 | {a, b, c}   | {2022-01-01 - 2022-01-03, 2022-01-05 - 2022-01-07, 2022-01-06 - 2022-01-09, 2022-01-08 - 2022-01-11} |
| 192.168.1.2 | {d, e}      | {2022-01-08 - 2022-01-11, 2022-01-10-2022-01-11} |
| 192.168.1.1 | {f}         | {2022-01-16 - 2022-01-18} |
```

Do you have any ideas on how to implement this?

I thought about using GraphFrames, but I don't even know where to start :S

Answer (score 2):

One way to identify overlapping date intervals it to use a cumulative conditional sum over a window partitioned by `ip` and ordered by `start_date`. For each row in a frame, if the `start_date` is greater than `max(end_date)` before the current row then it doesn't overlaps (i.e. it's a new group):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy('ip').orderBy('start_date')

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "previous_end", F.max("end_date").over(w)
).withColumn(
    "group",
    F.sum(F.when(F.lag("previous_end").over(w) < F.col("start_date"), 1).otherwise(0)).over(w)
).groupBy("ip", "group").agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.struct("user", F.struct("start_date", "end_date").alias("date_ranges"))
    ).alias("sessions")
).select(
    "ip", "sessions.user", "sessions.date_ranges"
)

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+-----------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|ip         |user     |date_ranges                                                                   |
#+-----------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|192.168.1.1|[a]      |[{2022-01-01, 2022-01-03}]                                                    |
#|192.168.1.1|[a, b, c]|[{2022-01-05, 2022-01-07}, {2022-01-06, 2022-01-09}, {2022-01-08, 2022-01-11}]|
#|192.168.1.2|[d, e]   |[{2022-01-08, 2022-01-11}, {2022-01-10, 2022-01-11}]                          |
#|192.168.1.2|[f]      |[{2022-01-16, 2022-01-18}]                                                    |
#+-----------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I think the solution is brilliant! I'll try it when I'm in front of the computer.

Comment: I've been looking at it, and it's not exactly the same. For example, if we observe the first group that is only user "a", that group should not exist since it is already included in group 2 (a, b, c).
I think you have to add a step to merge the groups and remove those "duplications". Perhaps something like GraphFrames with connected connections and check if there is an intersection of a single element of the users. But I think that could just be making a library call similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43915762/how-to-group-by-common-element-in-array