# Join and combine dataframe by array intersection

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join three different tables using an array of aliases as the join condition:

Table 1:
[image: table_1]

```py
table_1 = spark.createDataFrame([("T1", ['a','b','c']), ("T2", ['d','e','f'])], ["id", "aliases"])
```

Table 2:
[image: table_2]

```py
table_2 =spark.createDataFrame([("P1", ['a','h','e']), ("P2", ['j','k','l'])], ["id", "aliases"])
```

Table 3:

[image: table_3]

```py
table_3= spark.createDataFrame([("G1", ['a','n','o']), ("G2", ['p','q','l']), ("G3", ['c','z'])], ["id", "aliases"])
```

And I want to get a table like this:

| Aliases | table1_ids | table2_id | table3_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [n, b, h, o, a, e, d, c, f, z] | [T1, T2] | [P1] | [G1,G3] |
| [k, q, j, p, l] | [] | [P2] | [G2] |

Where all related aliases are in the same row and there is no repeated ID of the three initial tables. In other words, I am trying to group by a common alias and to collect all different IDs in which these aliases can be found.

**I have used Spark SQL for the code examples, but feel free of using Pyspark or Pandas.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide reproducible inputs

Comment: Why is d/**e**/f not grouped with a/b/c/h/**e**/n/o/z?

Comment: But for doing that I would need an auto-join, and I'm not sure that would be the best option.

Comment: So what is the logic exactly?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing. I don't really understand the logic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have modified the original question and clarify how I have implemented it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have thought about it and I think that what I described it's a Graph problem.  More precisely, I was trying to find all [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)), so 'aliases' + 'ids' will be the graph vertices, and once it has been found all the graph components (all the subgraphs that are not connected to other subgraph), it will be extracted the IDs from the results. It's very important to be able to differentiate the IDs from the values (aliases).

To implement a solution, I have used [Graphframes](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes) ([Thanks to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49675078/5475506)):

```py
from graphframes import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = table_1.unionAll(table_2).unionAll(table_3)

edgesDF = df.select(f.explode("Aliases").alias("src"),f.col("id").alias("dst")) # Columns should be called 'src' and 'dst'.
verticesDF = edgesDF.select('src').union(edgesDF.select('dst'))
verticesDF = verticesDF.withColumnRenamed('src', 'id')
graph=GraphFrame(verticesDF,edgesDF)

components_df = graph.connectedComponents(algorithm="graphx")
components_grouped_df = components_df.groupBy("component").agg(f.collect_set("id").alias("aliases"))
```

So now we will have a Dataframe like this:
[image: components_grouped_df]

And as we want to have each ID in a different column, we have to extract them from the 'aliases' column and to create three new ones. For doing so, we will use regex and a UDF:

```py
import re
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, ArrayType, DoubleType

df_schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("table_1_ids",ArrayType(StringType()),True),    
    StructField("table_2_ids",ArrayType(StringType()),True),
    StructField("table_3_ids",ArrayType(StringType()),True),
    StructField("aliases",ArrayType(StringType()),True)
  ])

@udf(returnType=df_schema)
def get_correct_results(aliases):
    regex_table_1 = "(T\d)"
    regex_table_2 = "(P\d)"
    regex_table_3 = "(G\d)"
    table_1_ids = []
    table_2_ids = []
    table_3_ids = []
    elems_to_remove = []
    for elem in aliases:
        result_table_1 = re.search(regex_table_1, elem)
        result_table_2 = re.search(regex_table_2, elem)
        result_table_3 = re.search(regex_table_3, elem)
        if result_table_1:
            elems_to_remove.append(elem)
            table_1_ids.append(result_table_1.group(1))
        elif result_table_2:
            elems_to_remove.append(elem)
            table_2_ids.append(result_table_2.group(1))
        elif result_table_3:
            elems_to_remove.append(elem)
            table_3_ids.append(result_table_3.group(1))
    return {'table_1_ids':list(set(table_1_ids)), 'table_2_ids':list(set(table_2_ids)),'table_3_ids':list(set(table_3_ids)), 'aliases':list(set(aliases) - set(elems_to_remove))}
```

So, finally, we use the previous UDF in the 'final_df':

```py
master_df = components_grouped_df.withColumn("return",get_correct_results(f.col("aliases")))\
.selectExpr("component as row_id","return.aliases as aliases","return.table_1_ids as table_1_ids","return.table_2_ids as table_2_ids", "return.table_3_ids as table_3_ids")
```

And the final DF will look like this:
[image: master_df]